# Random Assigning Treatment in Stata

Tags: random, stata, stata-macros

I need help with random assigning treatments in Stata, I am lost. The variable is assigned to be treated with at 45% probability.  After the variable has been assigned to be treated, I have to pick the treatment date by randomly drawing a specific time period.

Any help on how to do this. The code I created did not produce any results.

`gen effect = runiform(weight,.45)`

Comment: I don't understand the second part of your question about "randomly drawing a specific time period". Further detail is needed. It will be easier for others to help you if you provide a reproducible example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first part of your question, regarding randomly assigning a treatment with 0.45 probability, can be achieved by:

```
clear
set obs 100
gen id = _n

gen prob = runiform(0,1)

gen     treatment = 0
replace treatment = 1 if prob <= 0.45
```